# Maven POM dependency with added token based on profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml

We have a POM for our main project. I'd say 10 to 15 profiles are defined within. Dependencies are generic and probably number around 20 or so.

We have (at least) one dependency where its version depends on whether the profile is targeted for testing or production. Production deploys take:

```
<version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
```

as dependency version whereas dev and staging deploys take

```
<version>1.0.3.STAGING</version>
```

I'd like to set things up so that we don't have to switch this manually anymore. One obvious solution is to define the dependencies inside the profiles. The problem with that is the number of profiles we have. Each time the version number increases, we'd have to be careful not to miss updating a version somewhere.

I read about tokenizing, and tried declaring the generic dependency like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib-artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.${lib-artifactId.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then adding

```
        <properties>
            <lib-artifactId.version>RELEASE</lib-artifactId.version>
        </properties>
```

to each profile, with RELEASE changed to STAGING where appropriate.

That doesn't work. The error is to the effect that it cannot find the library with version

```
1.0.3.${lib-artifactId.version}
```

In other words, it's not substituting the token.

How would I solve this?

Comment: I already used this solution (profiles+property with different values) in a project and it worked perfectly. Are you sure profiles are correctly activated ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure insofar as all profiles work as intended and expected. One thing I considered is that, as all my profiles are in the pom.xml, maven might not be able to resolve the token because it's being defined many times (once for each profile).

Answer (score 0):

instead of defining the token in the profile, to substitute in to the dependency in the main file, you could try :

keep the dependency in each profile as you had before.  Replace the version by tokens ${lib-artifactId.release_version}  or ${lib-artifactId.staging_version} as appropriate, and define the two tokens in the top level pom file.

Comment: This wasn't bad, but it would require adding more information to the pom than I really want to.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using CLASSIFIERS from maven

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.groupId</groupId>
 <artifactId>lib-artifactId</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.3</version>
 <classifier>${lib-artifactId.version}</classifier>
</dependency>
```

It will resolve to 1.0.3-RELEASE

Comment: I like this, but it wasn't workable for me. The fact that it resolves to - (hyphen) RELEASE was a dealbreaker: It would require changing the name of the referred lib (it's name is with dots only, inspired by Spring releases, I reckon).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was what I thought didn't work initially. While it threw errors and made Eclipse crawl, it did compile and run. I then was able to solve the Eclipse error as well, so now I have the situation I want.

The problem with defining a generic dependency this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.${lib-artifactId.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

is that Eclipse (or at least m2e) has no way of finding the actual dependency when you're just coding and not 'inside' a certain profile. And so it throws nasty errors. Lots of red. Specifically:

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor org.groupId:lib-artifactId:jar:1.0.3.${lib-artifactId.version}: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.groupId:lib-artifactId:jar:1.0.3.${lib-artifactId.version} from http://xxx.xxx.xxx was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of xxx has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.groupId:lib-artifactId:jar:1.0.3.${lib-artifactId.version} from/to xxx (http://xxx.xxx.xxx): IllegalArgumentException
```

The solution isn't all that hard once you consider the problem. I just had to specify a 'default' version in the generic section's properties. So I added

```
<lib-artifactId.version>RELEASE</lib-artifactId.version>
```

to the section at the top and all was fine.